# Expand command and put result into a macro: Use of \value doesn't match its definition

Tags: macros, expansion

I still struggle with the expansion of Latex. I try to calculate the a real number from a date format and put this into a macro `\value`. I need to expand the command with `\edef` because I plan to use the value as a parameter in `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfcalendar} 

\newcount\mycount

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dateconvert}[1]{%
 \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\mycount}
 \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\mycount}{\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}
 \pgfmathparse{(\myday-1)/365+(\mymonth-1)/12+\myyear}\let\mydate\pgfmathresult
 \mydate
}

\dateconvert{2010-07-01} %works

\edef\value\dateconvert{2010-07-01}
\value %does not work: Use of \value doesn't match its definition

\end{document}
```

Calling `\dateconvert` directly works. However, when I try to copy the result into `\value`, it fails.

Comment: Since `\dateconvert` performs various assignments it’s not fully expandable. So you can’t use it in an `\edef` context. By the way, if `\dateconvert` were fully expandable you would have to write `\edef\value{\dateconvert{2010-07-01}}`.

Comment: @MartinL. In addition to the comments above, `\value` is a LaTeX kernel macro, so it's a _bad_ idea to redefine it: you should pick a different name!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this procedure right for you?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath} 
\usepackage{pgfcalendar} 

\newcount\mydatecount
\def\settodate#1#2{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#2}{\mydatecount}
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\mydatecount}{\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{(\myday-1)/365+(\mymonth-1)/12+\myyear}%
}

\begin{document}
\settodate\x{2010-07-01}
\settodate\y{2010-03-01}

\x{} and \y{}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

```
2010.5 and 2010.16666
```

Comment: I get an error when compiling your MWE (`! Undefined control sequence \pgfkeys`). This error disappears when using `\usepackage{pgf}` instead of `\usepackage{pgfmath}`.

Comment: Obviously `\pgfmathsetmacro` solved the problem. If I would use `\edef`  instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`, this would not work anymore. My question now: Since `\pgfmathsetmacro` only works for numbers, how would I solve the problem if the command would not set a number but a string.

Comment: @MartinL. That's somewhat different to the question here. Perhaps post a second question, linking to this and show the context of what you want to do. If all you want to do is store a string, why not just `\def\myvalue{<string>}`?

Answer (score 6):

The error you get arises from the fact that

```
\edef\value\dateconvert{2010-07-01}
```

defines `\value` as a macro which must be immediately followed by `\dateconvert` and which is replaced by the text `2012-07-01`. As mentioned in comments, you'd need

```
\edef\value{\dateconvert{2010-07-01}}
```

to set `\value` in the way you intend, but this requires that `\dateconvert` is expandable. As it performs an assignment, this is not the case (and indeed  `pgfmath` is not expandable at all).

One relatively simple approach is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand { \dateconvert } { m }
  { \dateconvert:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \dateconvert:n #1
  { \__dateconvert:w #1 \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__dateconvert:w #1 - #2 - #3 \q_stop
  { \fp_eval:n { #1 + ( #2 - 1 ) / 12 + ( #3 - 1 ) / 365 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcount\mycount

\begin{document}

\dateconvert{2010-07-01} %works

\edef\myvalue{\dateconvert{2010-07-01}}
\myvalue
\end{document}
```

This works using the expandable LaTeX3 FPU, and a simple set up for the date parsing: from the question, it's not clear now robust this needs to be. I've renamed `\value` to `\myvalue` as `\value` is a LaTeX kernel command, and you really should not use this name.